# if without curly braces

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code that generates a list of prime numbers.

```
<script>
    var num = prompt("enter limit")

    for(i = 2; i < num; i++)
    {
        if((i % 2 == 0 || i % 3 == 0))
            continue;

        document.write(i + " is a PRIME")
    }
</script>
```

My question is: why does the following code below does not run ; addition of the curly braces in the if statement.

```
<script>
    var num = prompt("enter limit")

    for(i =2; i < num; i++)
    {
        if((i % 2 == 0 || i % 3 == 0))
        {
            continue;
            document.write(i + " is a PRIME")
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @doctorWeird. When you are asking a question, please indent your code.

Answer (score 2):

The `if` statement makes the **one** statement attached to it conditional on the condition it tests. In your case, that **one** statement is `continue`.

When you use curly braces, you're making the one statement attached to the `if` a *block statement*, which is a statement that groups other statements together.

Your original code, correctly* indented, is:

```
var num = prompt("enter limit")

for (i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if ((i % 2 == 0 || i % 3 == 0))
        continue;
    document.write(i + " is a PRIME")
}
```

Again, as you can see, only the `continue` statement is attached to the `if`.

If you wanted to use a block statement, `continue` is all you would put in it to keep the same meaning:

```
var num = prompt("enter limit")

for (i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if ((i % 2 == 0 || i % 3 == 0)) {
        continue;
    }
    document.write(i + " is a PRIME")
}
```

---

* *(There are lots of "correct" ways to indent code. But you do need to use **one** of them, which you hadn't in your question, if you want the code to be clear.)*

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation is a bit wrong. The correct interpretation will be as follows

```
if((i % 2 == 0 || i % 3 == 0)) {
    continue;
}
document.write(i + " is a PRIME")
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `if` when without the curly brackets, only the code after the `if` statement executes, hence I assume that you want to `continue` only inside your `if` statement. Inorder to fix your code, you need to take out the `document.write` statement outside of the `if` condition.

```
var num = prompt("enter limit")

for (i = 2; i < num; i++) {
  if ((i % 2 == 0 || i % 3 == 0)) {
    continue;
  }

  document.write(i + " is a PRIME");
}
```

---

If you write your `if` statement like

```
if(YOUR_CONDITION_HERE)
  continue; //only this will be considered in the `if` statement
```

But if you write it as

```
if(YOUR_CONDITION_HERE) {
  continue; //this will be considered inside the if statement and also other code which is inside the curly braces.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does run; it just does not produce any output. Let's look at the pertinent code:

```
if((i % 2 == 0 || i % 3 == 0))
{
    continue;
    document.write(i + " is a PRIME")
}
```

If `i` does not meet the requirements of the conditional then the code execution does not enter the code block between the curly braces.  Simple enough explanation for that scenario.  But for when it does enter the code block, the first statement that it encounters is:

```
continue;
```

This causes the loop to continue without considering any further statements in the code block.  This is why placing the curly braces as you have produces no output.

As others have stated, you should just simply eliminate those particular curly braces in your code as shown in your first example.